# How to reset the content in HelpViewer 2.0,2.1 and 2.2?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, msdn, help-viewer

I found how to do this for Help Viewer 1.0: http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/news/moveorresetyourvs2010helplibrary#TOC-Moving-the-VS-2010-Help-Library. How can I reset the contents in the above versions?

Doing it from the UI seems to leave something behind, so I want a full blown reset.

Comment: The link in your question didn't point directly to [Resetting Help Library Content & Location](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/news/moveorresetyourvs2010helplibrary#TOC-Resetting-Help-Library-Content-Location). Did you see that and tried it for e.g. version 2.2?

Comment: I saw it, it is still for VS2010.